# Parent Process exit when using sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL)

Tags: c, process, zombie-process, sigaction

I am learning how sigaction SIGCHLD handles zombie process.
My expectation is child process sleep for 5-30 seconds (based on random number), parent process sleep for 30 seconds.

But it's weird that parent process exit before child process exit. Why?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

sig_atomic_t child_exit_status;

void clean_up_child_process(int signal_number){
  int status;
  wait(&status);
  child_exit_status = status;
}

int main(){
  struct sigaction sigchld_action;
  int random_number;
  pid_t child_pid;

  memset(&sigchld_action, 0, sizeof(sigchld_action));
  sigchld_action.sa_handler = &clean_up_child_process;
  sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (child_pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        printf("Child %d created\n", i);

        srand(time(NULL)^getpid());
        random_number = (rand()%25)+5;;
        printf("random number is %d\n", random_number);

        sleep(random_number); // Simulate some work in the child
        exit(0);
    }
  }

  sleep(30);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: the child sleeps for a time between 25 and 29 seconds.  It isn't very relevant to your problem.

Comment: Add more diagnostic printing.  The child should report when it exits.  The parent should loop, waiting before the children exit (as in: `int status; int corpse; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0) print("Parent %5d: child %5d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);`).  The parent should report when it exits.  And you need to worry about your interrupt handler.  Can it report its labours?  Should you set `SA_RESTART` in the flags?  Report the PID in the messages from the child process too.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the `sleep()` call returns when interrupted, telling you how many seconds of sleep time were left.  If the result is 0, it wasn't interrupted.  Otherwise, there was some time left.  When the first child exits at, say, 10 seconds, the `sleep()` call returns 20, and you should loop:

```
unsigned naptime = 30;
unsigned napleft;
while ((napleft = sleep(naptime)) != 0)
{
    printf("%5d: woke up with %u seconds left - leave me in peace!\n",
           getpid(), napleft);
    naptime = napleft;
}
printf("%5d: I'm awake again\n", getpid());

int status;
int corpse;
while ((corpse = wait(&status)) >= 0)
{
    print("Parent %5d: child %5d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
          getpid(), corpse, status);
}
```

Note that in multi-process code, it is usually helpful to identify which process is printing each message by including the PID.  Do not try to optimize `getpid()` calls by saving the value — that can easily lead to misleading diagnostics, which are worse than no diagnostics.  (In any case, `getpid()` is one of the fastest system calls; the overhead won't be measurable.)

In a comment, I mentioned the `SA_RESTART` flag for `sigaction()`.  I don't think that'll help because `sleep()` is not restartable.

Think about how you can report the exit status of the child that exits, but be aware of [How to avoid using `printf()` in a signal handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16891019/15168). Consider whether to replace `exit(0)` in the child code with `exit(i + 10)` so that you can tell from the exit status which child it was that reported it.